# Python Kubernetes Client equivalent of kubectl get pods

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to use the Python Kubernetes Client to get the run-time of each container for all my pods. Using the K8s CLI this information is available by using `kubectl describe pods`.

I can get the output for a single pod by using

```py
api_response = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name='pod-name',namespace='namespace-name')
```

However, I need this information for all the pods.

What is the equivalent of `kubectl get pods`for Python K8s library? I'm thinking I can use this to create a list of pods and use the mentioned command above to loop through them by their pod-name and get the required information.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#list_namespaced_pod) you can try this `api_response = api_instance.list_namespaced_pod(namespace='namespace-name')`

Answer (score 2):

You are right about using this command to get all pod names:

```
api_response = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name='pod-name',namespace='namespace-name')
```

But to get specifically the name of those, use something like this:

```
for i in api_response.items:
    print("%s" %(i.metadata.name))
```

That should work for you :)